# axios return data can not load vue list rendering?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Use the axios request api interface, and then return the data, but can not be loaded v-for to iterate through the properties of an object.

Look at the javascript file:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            movies: []
        },
        created() {
            this.getMovie();
        },
        methods: {
            getMovie: function () {
                axios.get("https://api.douban.com/v2/movie/top250")
                    .then(function (res) {
                        console.log(res.data.subjects);
                        this.movies = res.data.subjects;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            }

        }
    })
```

HTML file:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="title">
      <ul>
         <li v-for="(item,index) in movies">
            {{item.title}}
        </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

I believe everyone should be able to solve this my problem, but  I can't figure out how to up loading list data？
Look the jsfiddle Online code debugging tools:

[enter link jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/zhouyulong/c6b6osnx/)

Comment: Start by moving the v-for directive from <ul> to the <li>. That would create a bunch of lists with a single list item.

Comment: Edit edited, but can not be loaded.

Comment: Now change your functions to es6 arrow notation, () => {...}. That way you preserve `this` context when assigning this.movies

Comment: do you have any errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul v-if="movies.length > 0">
     <li v-for="(item,index) in movies">
        {{item.title}}
      </li>
</ul>

mounted() {
   this.getMovie();
},
```